Display ClangTidy results using Jenkins Next Generation Warnings Plugin
I have a Jenkins build which runs CppCheck static analysis on a large C++ project. The CppCheck output goes into the console log for Jenkins as XML. A Python script then aggregates all of the any issues found into a single XML file which is parsed using the Jenkins Next Generation Warnings plugin.
I am am trying to do something similar with clang-tidy static analysis. It is generating a number of warnings in the  console log which I can parse using Python. Unfortunately I cannot get  the Jenkins Next Generation Warnings plugin to find any issues, even though the log shows it s parsing the XML file I have generated.
The generated xml looks like:
<issues>
    <issue filename="C:\JenkinsJobs\User-Branch-Build\Windows-ClangTidy-User-Branch\Common\src\infrastructure\CSVParser.cpp" line="62" severity="warning">
    <category>cppcoreguidelines-init-variables</category>
    <message>variable 'uLineNumber' is not initialized</message>
    </issue>

    ... 
<issues>

The JenkinsFile call to parse it is
script {
    recordIssues(enabledForFailure: true,
                 failOnError: true,
                 tool: clangTidy(pattern: '**/clangtidy-*.xml'),
                 qualityGates: [[threshold: 1, type: 'TOTAL', unstable: true ]]
                 )
}

Jenkins output:
[Clang-Tidy] Searching for all files in 'c:\JenkinsJobs\User-Branch-Build\Windows-ClangTidy-User-Branch' that match the pattern '**/clangtidy-*.xml'
[Clang-Tidy] Traversing of symbolic links: enabled
[Clang-Tidy] -> found 1 file
[Clang-Tidy] Successfully parsed file c:\JenkinsJobs\User-Branch-Build\Windows-ClangTidy-User-Branch\build\Windows\clangtidy-issues.xml
[Clang-Tidy] -> found 0 issues (skipped 0 duplicates)

I have tried a number of different formats for the XML and so far I cannot get Jenkins to display/detect any issues.
If I generate the XML in the same format as CppCheck I can get Jenkins to display the issues as CppCheck Warnings by changing the Jenkinsfile call to tool: cppCheck(pattern: '**/clangtidy-*.xml'), but I would prefer to use the build in clangTidy tool.
For reference the XML format as used generated CppCheck is:
<results version="2">
    <cppcheck version="2.14"/>
    <errors>
        <error id="cppcoreguidelines-init-variables" severity="warning"
               msg="variable 'uLineNumber' is not initialized">
            <location file="C:\JenkinsJobs\User-Branch-Build\Windows-ClangTidy-User-Branch\MyFile.cpp"
                      line="62" column="17"/>
        </error>
    </errors>
</results>

What is the correct XML/JSON format for the clangTidy tool?
